# SwiftUI and Core Data: fetch based on user input

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I'm struggling with what I suspect is a very simple pattern, and I would appreciate a point in the right direction.  In short: I want to navigate from a master view (List) to a detail view (List), where the row tapped in the master list causes a core data fetch to populate the detail list.  For example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let makes = ["GMC", "Ford", "Chevy"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(self.makes, id: \.self) { make in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                  Text(make)
                } //NavigationLink
            } //List
        } //NavigationView
    } //body
} //ContentView
```

So if the user taps the row labeled "Chevy", I want to perform a core data fetch returning all Vehicle objects with make == "Chevy" and then use those Vehicles to populate the detail view list.  I know how to perform the fetch with the necessary predicate, but I can't figure out when/where to make that fetch happen when a row is tapped or how then to get the fetch results to the detail view.

Edit: And to clarify, I would like to avoid a pattern where the ContentView fetches all Vehicles up front, and then just filters them based on the selected make.  Instead, I would like a fetch to happen dynamically after the user taps a row.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be to let the `DetailView` to do the fetching, just pass the selected row to the `DetailView` and let it do it's job, you can place the fetching in `DetailView` init or better place it in the model's init.

But, maybe you do not want to perform the navigation if there are not data matching the selected row (it would be a bit ugly to display an empty list in DetailView), in this case you have to place the fetching in MasterView model and call it when a row was pressed, please see the answer I gave here earlier today https://stackoverflow.com/a/58723514/10208552, basically, you will tap a button that will trigger a fetching which will trigger a navigation

Comment: Thanks, Sorin:  this helped me figure out a solution.  I couldn't figure out how to do the fetching in DetailView's init, unfortunately.  But then I realized that I can do the fetching in a function called as the argument to List, within the body var of DetailView.  It also seems to work when called from the List's .onAppear.

Comment: @protasm Could you please share your solution? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Pass the make to your second view via a simple struct parameter e.g:

```
NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(make: make))
```

Your `DetailView` just needs that `make` parameter:

```
struct DetailView: some View {
    var make: String
}
```

Then use a predicated fetch request, which looks something like this:

```
 @FetchRequest(
    entity: Vehicle.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: [
        NSSortDescriptor(key: "model", ascending: true),
    ],
    predicate: NSPredicate(format: "make == %@", self.make)
) var vehicles: FetchedResults<Vehicle>
```

Please note this code is untested, but this should get you on the right path.

Comment: Thanks kdion:  I gave this a try, but Xcode didn't like the reference to 'self.make' in the @FetchRequest.  "Cannot use instance member 'make' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available."

Comment: This is not working as you can not use self when it hasn't initialized. Do the fetch request in the init() method