# Get rid of navigationbar inside a tabview

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this implementation:

View_1: containing a navigationView and 2 buttons like below

```
NavigationView {
                GeometryReader { gr in
                ZStack {
                    VStack(alignment: HorizontalAlignment.center, spacing: 10) {
                        HStack{
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        Text("1").foregroundColor(.white).padding(EdgeInsets(top: 30, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                        Text("2").foregroundColor(.white)
                        Spacer()
                        HStack {
                            NavigationLink(destination: SigninScreen()){
                                Text("Button 1")
                            }

                            Button(action: {}){
                                Text("Button 2")
                            }
                        }.padding()
                    }.background(Image("bg-welcome")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                }.navigationBarHidden(true)
            }
```

then the destination screen (SigninScreen):

```
struct SigninScreen: View {
    @State private var email: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Spacer()
            }
            Text("SigninScreen")
            VStack {
                TextField("Email", text: self.$email)
                .padding()
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 1).stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2))

                SecureField("Password", text: self.$password)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.white)
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 1).stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2))

                Button(action: {}){
                    NavigationLink(destination: MainScreen()){
                        Text("Sign in").foregroundColor(.white)
                    }


                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 40, bottom: 10, trailing: 40))
                        .border(Color.white)

                }
            }.padding()

            Spacer()
            }.background(Color.red).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(Edge.Set.all).navigationBarHidden(true)

    }
}

struct SigninScreen_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SigninScreen()
    }
}
```

And finally the last view:

```
struct MainScreen: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView(){
            HomeScreen()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "house")
                    Text("Home")
            }
            EventsScreen()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "calendar")
                    Text("Events")
            }
            NewsScreen()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "info")
                    Text("News")
            }

        }
    }
}

struct MainScreen_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainScreen()
    }
}
```

the homeview is implemented like below

```
struct HomeScreen: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack{
                Spacer()
            }
            Text("cacaca")
            Spacer()
        }.background(Color.yellow).padding(EdgeInsets(top: -150, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))

    }
}

struct HomeScreen_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeScreen()
    }
}
```

My issue is that navigationbar takes a space I would like to use on top of the view
And also I can't attach a title to homeview for instance, without adding a new navigationview. Which adds even more space on the top before the content I want to display.

Any idea of how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using the `NavigationView` to transition between views, but you don't actually want the features of a `NavigationView` (a title at the top, back button, trailing buttons, etc.)

So instead of having your main view be two levels deep in a `NavigationView`, I would recommend having three unstacked views: `WelcomeScreen`, `SigninScreen`, and `MainScreen`. Your content view should then present/transition between these views depending on your app's state.

There are a lot of possibilities for how to transition between them (having the views' opacity fade in and out, have the views slide in and off screen, etc.) See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58734192/3088606) for a full example with pictures, but it could look something like:

```
class LoginStateModel: ObservableObject {
    enum CurrentView {
        case welcome, login, home
    }

    @Published var currentView = CurrentView.login
}

struct StackOverflowTests: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = LoginStateModel()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if model.currentView == .welcome {
                WelcomeScreen()
            } else if model.currentView == .login {
                SigninScreen()
            } else {
                MainScreen()
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(model)
    }
}
```

The model is passed to children views with `.environmentObject` so that they can modify it (e.g., `SigninScreen` sets model to `.home` on successful login, or `MainScreen` sets model to `.login` on sign out).

---

As an addendum, you can actually set a new title for `MainScreen` by just including another `.navigationBarTitle` modifier somewhere in its `body` property (like on the `TabView`). But I'd still recommend getting rid of the `NavigationView`, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Use this extension to hide navigationbar

```
extension View {
  func hideNavigationBar() -> some View {
        self
          .navigationBarTitle(Text(""))
          .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```